# Custom game tags in Chessbase 17not showing in pgn export

Tags: chessbase

I recently treated myself to Chessbase 17.

When anotating my games I like to add a tag with the time control of the game. I have done this in the game's details and saved. I can see the custom tag in the game window but when I export to pgn the tag is not there. Is this normale or am I missing something?